# Why does the PHP function glob() return files that do not match the wildcard?

Tags: php, glob

In `data2` directory, I have these files:

[image]

With the following code (running on Mac), I want to only get the files that end with `.xls`:

```
$file_names = glob('data2/*.xls');
foreach ($file_names as $file_name) {
    echo $file_name . '<br/>';
}
```

I would expect that this code would return one file `27template.xls`, however, it also returns the files with `TEMP` in them and adds a `.xls` to them:

[image]

**Added**: also if I change `smaller.xls` to `smaller.xlsx` then it does NOT find it as expected, but if I change it to `smaller.NNN` it finds `smaller.NNN.xls`.

**How can I use `glob()` to only get `.xls` files?**

Comment: Can't reproduce on Mac OS X 10.6.5 with PHP 5.3.0. Returns only `27template.xls` as expected for me.

Comment: Are you sure the files do not have this extension, hidden in your UI?

Comment: thanks for reproducing this, it turns out that my OSX Finder is not showing me the actual names of my files, anyone know why? http://superuser.com/questions/227256/how-can-i-get-finder-to-show-me-the-real-names-of-my-files

Comment: @Edward: It's because Finder hides file extensions by default (as does, I believe, Windows Explorer).

Comment: @Edward: You can make file extension visible via "Get Info" (context menu or press Command+i) and tick "Show file extension".

Comment: @BoltClock & @Damiqib's comments should be compiled as an answer.. that is the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is because the extension you are looking at might be not the real one (hided by default on Finder). You can check the real extension by clicking on the file and click on "Get info". If you want to show the extensions of all file you have to follow the steps by the Apple documentation:

> To show the extension for all files, choose Finder > Preferences and click Advanced, then select "Show all file extensions."

Answer (score 0):

A filename like data2/smaller.xlsTEMP.xls does match your glob expression of data2/*.xls, so it will be returned by glob... are you sure that it doesn't exist? (perhaps the Mac equivalent of Windows hidden)

Try combining two glob expressions with array_diff()

```
$file_names = array_diff(glob('data2/*.xls'),glob('data2/*.*.xls'));
```

The second glob returns those entries that you don't want, then the array_diff() filters that set out of the result from the first glob

**EDIT**

or try calling clearstatcache() just before your glob, in case PHP has cached directory entries from a previous query